# Failing to push some refs when trying to get GitHub to work with multiple accounts

Tags: git, github

I have a repo up in my personal account that I'm trying to push to without pushing to my company's account. So to manage my accounts, I followed [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts/) to differentiate when I was pushing to my personal GitHub account vs my Company's account.

I added the config file within my `~/.ssh`, which looks like this:

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

When I cd into the Rails project I'm trying to push to my Repo, I run the following in my command line per the tutorial:

```
git remote add origin git@github-personal:myaccount/POP.git
```

Then I try:

```
git push -u origin master
```

However I get the following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github-personal:travisvalentine/POP.git'
```

I'm a beginner with Git and all, so I'd appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Rails project, make sure you have added (`git add`) and committed the files before pushing.

The tutorial that you linked to just says `git init` and then `git commit -am`, which is wrong ( or atleast, not really helpful for beginners)